# SPRING REST is de-serializeing properties without setters

Tags: spring, rest

I have a class without a setter, to avoid setting from the client-side.
but I still get the value in the REST method...

```
public class Entity implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private SystemUserEntity createdBy;

    public SystemUserEntity getCreatedBy(){
       return this.createdBy;
    }
}
```

this is my PUT method:

```
@PutMapping("/some-request/")
public void update(@RequestBody Entity entity) {

}
```

this problem is that the `entity` variable has createBy value...
How can it be? it is  `READ_ONLY` and has no setter?

Thanks

Comment: Add @JsonProperty to the getter only, not to the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jackson, a getter will make a private field both serializable and deserializable. a setter makes a private field deserializable only.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Entity {
    private String createdBy;
    private int val;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }
}

@Test
    public void testReadOnly() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String test = "{\"createdBy\": \"2019-09-04\", \"val\": 1}";
        Entity entity = objectMapper.readValue(test, Entity.class);
        assertEquals(1, entity.getVal());
        assertNull(entity.getCreatedBy());
    }
```